# Validator new textbox c#

Tags: c#, winforms, validation

How to create a validator from the textbox class or create new textbox, rather than dragging the textbox from the toolbox

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    createTextpass();
    // Creating and setting the properties of TextBox1
    TextBox textboxUsername = new TextBox();
    textboxUsername.Location = new Point(420, 50);         
    textboxUsername.Size = new Size (300,30);
    textboxUsername.Name = "text_user";
    this.Controls.Add(textboxUsername);

    TextBox textboxPassword = new TextBox();
    textboxPassword.Location = new Point(420, 80);
    textboxPassword.Size = new Size(300, 30);
    textboxPassword.Name = "text_pass";
    this.Controls.Add(textboxPassword);

    TextBox textboxMail = new TextBox();
    textboxMail.Location = new Point(420, 110);
    textboxMail.Size = new Size(300, 30);
    textboxMail.Name = "text_mail";
    this.Controls.Add(textboxMail);
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at msdn? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/input-keyboard/validation?view=netdesktop-6.0

Comment: What is your actual issue? I don't see anything about validation in the code you posted so it's not clear what you're actually asking for.

Comment: If you remove the call to a non-existent(?) (or at least not shown in your code) method `createTextpass();`, then your code runs without error and creates the text boxes.  So what exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add the texbox width and height

Comment: Not necessary. By specifying `Size` the width and height is set automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly. You want to create a textbox and check whether valid text is entered in this textbox or not. For example, the following code can be used for `textboxUsername`:

```
public TextBox textboxUsername;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    createTextpass();
    // Creating and setting the properties of TextBox1
    textboxUsername = new TextBox();
    textboxUsername.Location = new Point(420, 50);
    textboxUsername.Size = new Size(300, 30);
    textboxUsername.Name = "text_user";            
    this.Controls.Add(textboxUsername);
    textboxUsername.TextChanged += new EventHandler(usernameTextbox_TextChanged);

    ....
}

    
//If textboxUsername contains the # character, an alarm will be displayed
protected void usernameTextbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (textboxUsername.Text.Contains('#'))
      MessageBox.Show("inavlid char in userName");
}
```